# I create input field using jquery, how can keep this ' new input value ' exist after refresh page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I create input field using jquery, how I can keep this ' new input value ' exist after refresh page

the code is

```
function onMyButtonclick() 
        {   var a =$('#addItem').val()
            $('#resultList').append('<li>'+a +'</li>');
            $('#addItem').val("");

        }
<input type="button"  value="add" onClick="onMyButtonclick();">
<ol id="resultList">
    <li>just example</li>
</ol>
</form>
```

solution is so important ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [localstorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage#localStorage)

```
var data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('a')) || [];
//do something with data array
data.push($('#addItem').val());
localStorage.setItem('a', JSON.stringify(data));
```

Comment: I run that code but it doesn't do what I want can you assist me

Answer (score 2):

You have to understand that on page refresh, the DOM is reconstructed again, so there is no straight way to have this "new input value" exist after page refresh, since it was added to the DOM programmatically on user interaction.

But not withstanding, you have other mechanism in the browser that can be used to persist information even on page refresh. You have [cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.cookie), and other set of Storage related feature which includes localStorage, sessionStorage, globalStorage. You can read about these features here [DOM Storage Guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage). for your situation, LocalStorage would be most appropriate.

So basically the solution you need would have you modify the `onMyButtonClick` function to store the information about the input item that has been added in any of the above browser persistence mechanism. And when the page loads again on refresh, you write a new function that takes information that you stored to generate the input elements again.

I would also advice you read the article: [THE PAST, PRESENT & FUTURE OF LOCAL STORAGE FOR WEB APPLICATIONS](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html)